# Wrap a timeseries to generate daywise grouped rolling statistics

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently in the process of refactoring an algorithm that does analysis on a timeseries, because the implementation is too slow for anything but prototyping use.

The algorithm generates a `DataFrame` by slicing the timeseries into 24h chunks and arranges them side by side, so that each column consists of 24h of timeseries data.

The next step is to loop over each day (column), comparing the (rolling) statistics of that day to a combined (rolling) statistic of the 7 previous days (columns) (the SNR of the data is very bad so days are combined to enhance it). The problem is that this is a for loop in python itself that takes slices from the `DataFrame` via `df.loc[]`, which is extremely slow.

I would like to use native pandas methods as much as possible to speed up the algorithm, however i'm a bit stuck at this point.

I suppose to generate the rolling "reference" statistics (made up from the previous 7 days) in one command instead of a loop, i should arrange the data into a big diagonal `DataFrame` like so

```
[[day 0] [day 1] [day 2] [day 3] [day 4] [day 5] [day 6] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] ...
 [nan..] [day 1] [day 2] [day 3] [day 4] [day 5] [day 6] [day 7] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] [nan..] ...
etc.]
```

Then i could simply apply df.rolling(foo).whatever().

I tried generating such a `DataFrame` as above with the help of `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("1d"))` but i can't think of a way to do it without loops.

If anybody knows of a way how to generate such a frame or can think of a better way to tackle this, i would appreciate the help.

Edit:
Thinking some more about this, the `DataFrame` could also look like this

```
[[day 0] [day 1] [day 2] [day 3] [day 4] [day 5] [day 6]
 [day 1] [day 2] [day 3] [day 4] [day 5] [day 6] [day 7]
 etc.]
```

which looks like a subset of a Hankel matrix where each element is a time series of 24h of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was way easier than i thought initially. Looking at the second example, one can see that each column is simply a copy of the original timeseries shifted by one more day.

What i came up with:

```
# duplicate timeseries
refFrame = pd.concat([data] * refLen, axis=1)

# shift each column by samples per day * day index
refFrame = refFrame.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-int(x.name) * 144),
                          axis=0)
# drop rows that contain nan after shifting
refFrame.dropna(inplace=True)
```